# Why do some questions with reopen votes not show up in the Reopen Review Queue?

Tags: discussion, review, vote-to-reopen

It was recently brought to my attention that Programmers.SE now has a [Reopen Review Queue](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/review/reopen). I checked it out and found 1 question awaiting review, however the 10k tools show 13 questions with reopen votes.

What determines if a question shows up in the Reopen Review Queue or not? It can't just be if it has reopen votes or not, or I'd see 13 questions in that queue.

Comment: FYI the queue is available on all sites, not just Programmers.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

There's a "leave closed" button in the queue. If a certain number (currently 3) users click it for a given question, it'll drop out of the queue.

Without this, questions would remain in the queue indefinitely until they either got re-opened or deleted. The purpose of the queue is to give questions some additional exposure, on the off-chance that they *should* be re-opened - not to make reopening a sure-thing.

(BTW: the close queue works exactly the same way)

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, although questions wouldn't remain in the queue indefinitely since votes expire after a few days of no new votes :)

Comment: @Rachel Close/re-open votes only expire on questions with > 100 views.

Comment: I think the formula should change from 3 to `3 + numReopenVotes`. Otherwise, if 4 people think it should be reopened, and 3 people don't, it still disappears. Unless that's your desired behavior. Because the votes expire if it's not reopened, it wouldn't remain indefinitely.