# Why is reopen votes count different in the review queue and question itself

Tags: support, review, vote-to-reopen

[question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18337043/detect-startup-programs-on-windows-in-c-application) shows **4** *reopen* votes have been cast.

[review queue](https://stackoverflow.com/review/reopen/2764579) shows **3** *wanted to reopen*

Why is there the difference of **1** vote in between the two?

Not literally *Who*, but what type of user cast the **1** vote?

[related](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/151698/why-do-some-questions-with-reopen-votes-not-show-up-in-the-reopen-review-queue) although not my answer

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The discrepancy is due to the fact that someone probably voted directly from the question and not the review queue.  Only actions performed in the review queue will be recorded in the [summary that you linked](https://stackoverflow.com/review/reopen/2764579)

This is not an inclusive list but one of the following are likely sources of the 4th vote:

- the OP who cast his reopen vote since that user has access to the close votes on his own question (has he has greater than 250 rep)
- drive-by voter who saw a closed question and didn't think it should be closed
- someone who was watching the question, saw it edited and voted to reopen,
- a close voter who did the right thing and checked back on the post to see if it was improved.

Comment: Makes sense, probably it's the first vote by OP himself. (Think user can vote to close his own questions no matter the rep)

Comment: @Sha was just adding that exact thought myself

Comment: 250 rep privilege @ShaWizDowArd http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/view-close-votes

Comment: yea my guess is also that it's the OPs vote. How can we know that for sure

Comment: @mehow I thought you didn't literally want to know *who*?  Or do you mean just mean what type of user?

Comment: not literally the username but the type of user. if the owner has voted to reopen that unfortunately identifies him in this particular case, but also gives a black-on-white answer to who the missing voter is. If that's the case, then it will **always** be the same person if 1 vote is missing.

Comment: @mehow sorry, I realized that have I hit send... there's no way for us mortal to know if/when the post is reopened, at which time the names will be captured in the revision history.

Comment: @mehow it won't always be the OP, it could be any of the people I mentioned.  Since editing bumps a post and there are plenty of views on a post and any of those viewers with >3K rep could be the 4th voter.

Comment: @psubsee2003 you are right, I agree and clearly see your point now. Thanks for your answer

Comment: @mehow and in this [specific case](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/18337043/revisions), it *was* the OP

Comment: @psubsee2003 yea i see now. im voting to close again but for the proper reason now :)